# how to use sort.and() in spring

Tags: java, spring, sorting, jpa

If I want some data to be sorted by name ascending and label(which is taged on all data), is this possible to use like this:

```
Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "name")
                .and(new Sort("label"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this:

```
Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "name")
            .and(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "label"));
```

Comment: In fact, label is a boolean type so if some data’s label is true, I wanna take them to top or bottom of the list.

Comment: It will work if label is boolean also. If some data's label is false, it will take them top of the list and true labelled data to the bottom of list.

Answer (score 1):

Use this one, it can be helpful:

If label is boolean and order is ascending, then it will sort false first, since in the database true and false are represented as 1 and 0, respectively.

> So you can use desc order to get true first.

```
Sort sort = Sort.by(
    Sort.Order.asc("name"),
    Sort.Order.desc("label"));
```

Comment: @jjungdev, Is this helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort a query result in descending order by using the value of the description field and in ascending order by using the value of the title field, we have to create the Sort object separately: eg: new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "description") .and(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "title"));